# What does "invalid frame" mean exactley after a transform is performed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a simple app that allows a user to drag / scale an image on the screen using the pan and pinch gesture recognizers. It's common knowledge from the Apple API that after you perform a transform, as I am doing in my scale method, that the frame becomes "invalid". Being that I continually use the frame of my imageview to calculate the scale size and translation distance even after I have performed a transform and everything continues to work fine, I'm wondering what about the frame has become invalid?

I ask this, because now I am trying to crop the image that has been moved around and scaled, and I'm using its frame value to determine the crop area, and I'm getting funny results. I'm wondering if the invalid frame might be the problem, or if it could be something else. Here is my code for your reference:

```
CGRect croppedRect = CGRectMake(fabsf(self.oldImageView.frame.origin.x), fabsf(self.oldImageView.frame.origin.y), 316, 316);
CGImageRef croppedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.oldImageView.image.CGImage, croppedRect); 
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: croppedImageRef];
CGImageRelease(croppedImageRef);
UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: croppedImage];
```

Comment: are you sure its invalid and not invalidated? those things are different

Comment: invalidated means it needs to be redrawn, it doesn't mean the size is wrong. I have no clue what invalid means in this context

Comment: @Dani: I believe CoDEFRo is referring to this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid frame = funny results.

I think invalid means it is not guaranteed to have the wrong value, but it might. You've been getting away with using the frame by luck.

If you have a transformed view, and you need the frame, you can use this code:

```
CGRect frame = [[view superview] convertRect:view.bounds fromView:view];
```

As long as it's not rotated. If it's rotated, the "frame" can't be represented as a CGRect, which can only represent rectangles aligned with the axes. You can use `convertPoint` to convert each of the corners of the bounds, if that information is of any use to your program.

Or to set the frame if it's not rotated

```
view.bounds = [view convertRect:newFrame fromView:[view superview]];
```

Comment: I read your code more carefully, and I'm not sure this answer will solve your problem. But you should apply it to the other cases where you use frame, because that code might be unreliable.

Comment: Thanks for that, that line of code is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the frame anyway in that case. Frame is defined in the superview's coordinate system. You specify the argument to CGImageCreateWithImageInRect in the image's coordinate system, which I suspect is the same as the image view's coordinate system, even when transformed. You should use bounds in place of frame in that code. Either that or (0.0, 0.0) as the origin. I can't tell quite what you're trying to achieve.